# Get raw file from repository

Tags: git, api, gitlab

I want to get a file content in gitlab by using its api.
Firstly, I check my gitlab version, its written as,
GitLab Community Edition 9.4.3 b125d21 update asap

Then I create a private token and 
http://gitadress/api/v4/projects/id/repository/files?private_token=PRIVATE_TOKEN
returns as;

```
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
```

then I modify the query as;

http://gitadress/api/v4/projects/222/repository/tree?private_token=PRIVATE_TOKEN 
this request returns as;

```
[{"id":"8078365d80c","name":"test.js","type":"blob","path":"test.js","mode":"100644"}]
```

What I want is to get the content of the test.js but whatever I tried I couldn't achieve it.

http://gitadress/api/v4/projects/id/repository/tree/test.js/raw?private_token=PRIVATE_TOKEN&ref=master
returns as;

```
{"error":"404 Not Found"}
```

How can I get the raw file content by using gitlab api?
Documentation is here;
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/doc/api/repository_files.md#get-raw-file-from-repository

Comment: The linked doc mentions that the file path should be URL-encoded. Normally `.` is URL-safe, but the example encodes it anyway... so did you try with `test%2Ejs` instead?

Comment: Have you tried `http://gitadress/api/v4/projects/id/repository/files/test.js/raw?private_token=PRIVATE_TOKEN&ref=master` (with `tree` changed to `files`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation mentions:

> **Url encoded** full path to new file. Ex. `lib%2Fclass%2Erb`

That means you need to URL encode `test.js`: `test%2Ejs`.
(See [Percent encoding: character data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Character_data))

```
http://gitadress/api/v4/projects/id/repository/files/test%2Ejs/raw?private_token=PRIVATE_TOKEN
```

You can add `?ref=master` to make sure to get the content from the `master` branch for instance.

```
http://gitadress/api/v4/projects/id/repository/files/test%2Ejs/raw?ref=master&private_token=PRIVATE_TOKEN
```

That being said, you have the [gitlab-ce issue 31470](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/31470) which is still open:

> ### API to "Get raw file from repository" fails for files with dots

A fix is in progress: [gitlab-ce merge_request 13370](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/merge_requests/13370), and will be delivered for GitLab 9.5.

Comment: i change as you suggest.  and modified as; http://gitadress/api/v4/projects/:id/repository/files/test%2Ejs/raw?private_token=PRIVATE_TOKEN&ref=master but this return as; {"message":"404 File Not Found"} I really couldn't understand the situation. I am sure that there is a file and its name is test.js. What could be the problem?

Comment: @mmu36478 did you replace the id by your project id? (222 I believe in your case)

Comment: @mmu36478 I have edited my answer. There is a pending bug, which will be fixed in GitLab 9.5

Comment: now I get it. You are right, I try it with a file which doesn't include "." character. and query worked.